# How to configure IdentiyServer settings on appSettings.json of .NET Core?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4

I use IdentityServer in my Angular app based on .NET Core and I am trying to set some of the parameters like `client_id`, `redirect_uri`, `authority` in `appSettings.json` file.

```
"IdentityServer": {
  "Key": {
    "Type": "Development"
  },
  "Authentication": {
    "Authority": "localhost:8081",
    "ClientId": "localhost:8081",
    "AppIdUri": "localhost:8081"
  }
}
```

So, how can I do this?

I need to set these parameters via `appSettings.json` and retrieve them when using the following url: `https://localhost:8081/_configuration/DemoProject.Web`

Comment: @user2250152 What is that? I do not use amazon aws.

Comment: Does anybody else have no idea about Identity Server and .NET Core?

Comment: Are you basically asking how to read values from `appsettings.json`? What exactly `set these parameters via appSettings.json` mean? Clarify your question.

Comment: I am a little bit confused, sorry. But I need to set these parameters via `appSettings.json` and retrieve them when using the following url: `https://localhost:8081/_configuration/DemoProject.Web`. So, does this url open the parameters in `appsettings.json`? I don't think so, but I just set these parameters and retrşieve these paraneters via this url. Any help pls?

Answer (score 1):

You can call your settings in your code like this:

```
string ClientId = Configuration["IdentityServer:Authentication:ClientId"];
```

I hope this helps. If it is not what you ment let me know.

Comment: Thanks amigo, but I need to set these parameters via `appSettings.json` and retrieve them when using the following url: `https://localhost:8081/_configuration/DemoProject.Web`

Comment: Can't you make them an api call then? So you can call them and read them out and post them back? Or what is the situation you are in?

Comment: Sorry, but I could not understand, because I am new in IdentityServer and very confused. So, I simply try to changes IdentityServer parameters using `appsettings.json`.

Comment: I think you want to change the `launchsettings.json` these are the settings for launching your application.